# How to write dynamic search query for Spring-Data-Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am implementing search on node attributes. Suppose I have a millions node of User with attributes name, location, income.

`n:user (name:"abc",location:"xyz", income:"123")
 n:user (name:"def",location:"ghj", income:"1877")`

I want to search User either with name or location or income or the combination of attributes like name and location etc. I can perform this search with simple cypher query 
`@Query("MATCH(n:user{location:{xyz},}) RETURN n") or

@Query("MATCH(n:userr{location:{xyz},name:{abc}}) RETURN n")`

But i don't want to do like that, i just want to pass the search parameter and create search query at runtime with the requested parameter. In `neo4template` class, got this method `query(String statement, Map<String,Object> params)` Now i am clueless, any detailed answer would be appreciated, as i am new to neo4j.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, parameter maps cannot be used in MATCH patterns.

So I believe you cannot use universal query like:

```
@Query("MATCH(n:user{0}) RETURN n")
public List<User> complexFind(Map<String, Object> props);
```

I'd suggest building query string dynamically, using string concatenation, and executing it later on with smth like that:

```
neo4template.query(YourQueryStringBuilder.build(search_params), other_params);
```

Comment: yes, thats what i want. Building Query string dynamically. can you post a short example on it.